# How to send info in body using post method in java class file

Tags: java, post

I requested to send some parameters from java file using post method. I did

```
 String urlParameters = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
URL url = new URL("http://testing/index.jsp");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

writer.write(urlParameters);
writer.flush();
```

But from receiver's end asks me to send it in body instead of url parameter. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please explain me how this code will work and what changes has to be done if I want to send info in request body.

Answer (score 0):

i believe  you either need to call the connect() method on the URLConnection at the end, or call a method that would cause the connect to be called for you, like fetching the resulting input stream.

Also you should think about what format the body should be in. Often people like to use standard formats like json, but you will have to decide that between you and the people implementing the server.